# Submodules and $p$-adic numbers

Tags: representation-theory, modules

I am a little bit confused about the terminology of simple $\mathbb{Q}_p[G]$ module.

E.j.: If one take an $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ module $M$, then $pM$ is a submodule, so one can just look for indecomposable $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ modules, not simple. Why is this different when taking a $\mathbb{Q}_p[G]$ module $N$, shouldn't $pN$ be a submodule?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Q_p$ is a field, so $pN=N$ for all $\mathbb Q_p$-modules $N$.

Comment: Ahh, you are right! Thank you. (Somehow I need to wait 12 minutes to accept the answer)

Comment: Yeah, Stack Exchange doesn't want you to accept an answer quickly - there might be a better answer that someone is taking some care to write, and hence taking a little longer.